# Android/Iphone device data distinction in web-application?

Tags: android, iphone, database-design, data-binding

So, I am working on the database architecture of a web application which would have its android and iphone apps developed also.

And for that I want to create a column name `device_id` in `mysql database` to track if a user is using the application via **web-app** or **android-app** or **iphone-app**.

Below are a few functional points :

**Creation / Sign Up**

- Can be done by web-app / android-app / iphone-app.

**Log In**

- Doesn't matter where the user creation has been done from , User can login from all based on the central database on web (using a login web service).

**Problem Domain**

> Don't have any facts but some of my tech team has advised that:

**Iphone** and **Android** those would provide a **UDID** and **ANDROID_ID** earlier are not going to do so in the future releases.

Now,

The mobile app works even without the internet connection and hence I have developed a sync tool for the same which will sync the data on **device to web** and **web to device** on a button click.

Some cases may include **same user, who is using the app from various devices and web as well** so that the data gets in sync on the device and web seamlessly.

Hence, what would be the best work-around for this, could I auto generate some unique sequence and not rely on the device id's for the syncing process.

---Edit---

> On factory reset and rooted device its sure that the device won't
>   return a unique Id and also there are various development firms
>   working on android customization and hence it is not a guarantee for a
>   unique device id . So, how could I get a better workaround by some
>   logic at my end and web also.

Comment: Does the user login (web) using a username/password combination? If so, can't you also use that on mobile devices?

Comment: @jlordo Obviously It can work but again as I have stated this is not the issue but I want to keep track from what device the user is logging in and sync to that particular device only. And how does it guarantee that if I have done the syncing from one device and not the other.

Comment: I read it will sync after a button click. So, after you click the button on your device, it will build a connection to your server, sync, and close that connection. That way, it will be synced to only that device.

Comment: _Are you solving the problem right?_ and _Are you solving the right problem?_ are two different questions ;)

Comment: @jlordo Later on suppose I want to generate a report about how many devices are being used by a person for using the same app , how could I do that?

Comment: If it's important to know it's the same device, even after flashing different roms, then I don't know if it's possible at all. Did you consider using the devices MAC Address? It survives flashing different roms.

Comment: I am not sure but an answer below is saying something about that. Are you talking about the same.

Comment: Something like that, but I think the answer below will generate different IDs for the same device with different roms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23617/discussion-between-pks-and-jlordo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing you are done with sync process(@Nishant B's post), now for Unique ID here is the code snippet which works almost for all Android devices (Tab + Mobile).

Now as you know, there is no guarantee of any Unique ID in Android so its better to create a key which will generate as a combination of multiple key and Unique on every time we generate...

```
TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String szImei = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); // Requires READ_PHONE_STATE

String m_szDevIDShort = "35" + //we make this look like a valid IMEI
Build.BOARD.length()%10+ Build.BRAND.length()%10 +
Build.CPU_ABI.length()%10 + Build.DEVICE.length()%10 +
Build.DISPLAY.length()%10 + Build.HOST.length()%10 +
Build.ID.length()%10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length()%10 +
Build.MODEL.length()%10 + Build.PRODUCT.length()%10 +
Build.TAGS.length()%10 + Build.TYPE.length()%10 +
Build.USER.length()%10 ; //13 digits


WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

BluetoothAdapter m_BluetoothAdapter = null; // Local Bluetooth adapter
m_BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String m_szBTMAC = m_BluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
String m_szWLANMAC = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();


String m_szLongID = m_szImei + m_szDevIDShort + m_szWLANMAC + m_szBTMAC;
// compute md5
MessageDigest m = null;
try {
     m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

m.update(m_szLongID.getBytes(),0,m_szLongID.length());
// get md5 bytes
byte p_md5Data[] = m.digest();
// create a hex string
String m_szUniqueID = new String();

for (int i=0;i<p_md5Data.length;i++) {
        int b = (0xFF & p_md5Data[i]);
// if it is a single digit, make sure it have 0 in front (proper padding)
if (b <= 0xF) m_szUniqueID+="0";
// add number to string
     m_szUniqueID+=Integer.toHexString(b);
}

// hex string to uppercase
m_szUniqueID = m_szUniqueID.toUpperCase();
```

here we had taken IMEI, Manufacturer Board detail, Wifi address and Bluetooth address (not taking ANDROID_ID as its change when factory reset). with combinition of these key one can generate a Unique key(`m_szUniqueID`) with the help of MD5.

I'm sure with the help of this above you can generate a unique key everytime.

Good points:

- Its not vary on consecutive generation on same device which mean one device will have only one ID and i.e. Unique.
- Even work with non registered device i.e. device without IMEI numbers.
- works with Tablet too.

Answer (score 2):

You are on right track for Sync process.

Device UDID (for iPhone) and Android_ID (for Android) is used for Push Notification only.

You can achieve Sync process without this.

For that, you need to follow below steps:

1) When app opens first time in device (iPhone/Android) then pass blank ("") date on server. So it will give you all data.

2) Store all data in local database for offline use. And also store server date locally.

3) Now, when user will open app next time, then pass previously stored data on server and it will give only latest added/updated data.

4) Make necessary changes add/edit in local database.

5) This way, you will have same data in web and both apps (iPhone & Android).

6) When user make changes in local data then set it's bit as "TRUE" in local database. So then when next sync perform, then check the SET bit and upload all data to server.

7) So, all data will be up-to-date at all web, iphone and android.

Hope you got an idea.

Happy Coding.

Cheers!

Comment: I am clear on the idea of sync but I didn't get your trick about the blank date that has to be send to the server for the first time. Also the algo for syncing is done but what I just messed up with is the unique ID issue  . One more doubt would it be fine to say that `ANDROID_ID` and `UDID` are going to be obsolete.

Comment: Blank date means: you are syncing the data first time. So if you pass "blank" date then server will return all data along with server date. Now, store that server date locally. And when you sync second time or further, then pass previously stored server date, so server will return updated data after that passed server date. Got it.

Comment: @pKs: How do you handle sync in following scenario: Someone uses the app on Android (daily), and then (after months) switches to iOS. How is the first sync to the iOS device handled?

Comment: @jlordo If someone uses android app daily and has not synced the app with the web then if he switches to iOS he would be having a fresh database downloaded from web as web doesn't know the state of android device or activity performed on it. **But in another case where user has synced the android app with web, and he swithches to iOS after months then on first time login from the iOS app the associated tables with particular changes would be downloaded and filled on the iOS device**

Comment: @pKs: perfect. I hope, jlordo got an answer.